# How difference an iOS token device from Android one

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an iOS and an Android mobile app. Both are registred on Amazon SNS applications, then I have two different ARNs.
If some customer download some of my apps, it going to generate a TokenDevice.
Then I need to send him/her a push notification, but first I need to create an endpoint on Amazon, something like this (Scala code):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDvgw.jpg

Where "x" must be changed by my Android App's ARN or by iOS App's ARN.

Is there a way to define if a TokenDevice was generated from Android or iOS device?

I need something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppmn5.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Token Device is hexadecimal (0–9, A, B, C, D, E, F).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `CreatePlatformEndpoint`, you should add [`customUserData`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput.html#//api/name/customUserData) to indicate the platform. You can get the custom user data by calling `GetEndpointAttributes`.

Comment: But in this moment I have only the TokenDevice, what platform should I set on customUserData? Considering that the TokenDevice was generated by iOS or Android, and I don't know which of them generated it. Thanks